# Wrong Fragment Picked using View Pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, view

I have Three different Fragments to show using View Pager. I have added the fragment to the adapter as follows. Title shown is correct but on click its picking the wrong fragment

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new AcceptsFragment(), "Accepts");
        adapter.addFragment(new AskedFragment(), "Asked");
        adapter.addFragment(new HelpedFragment(), "Helped");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Here is my adapter implementation.

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.d("Fragment Clicked ",String.valueOf(position));
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            //return mFragmentList.size();
            return mFragmentist.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't find any mistakes in you code. did you use a wrong order when addFragment.

Comment: share the missing source code, it seems all ok

Comment: Yes, it was actually ok. Problem was that when I use to click a fragment, it was loading next fragment as well which is obvious.